# SQL query, using group functions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
Select department_id, max(avg(salary)) 
From employees
Group by department_id
```

The above query gives the error

> ORA-00937: not a single-group function

I want to display the average salary for each department and also the maximum average salary from the departments. There are multiple departments. I'm using oracle 11g.

Comment: If you would care to formulate your required functionality a bit more carefully, you would get less answers;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the department with the maximum average salary -- and want only one row in the case of ties, you can simply do:

```
select e.*
from (select department_id, avg(salary) as avg_salary
      from employees
      group by department_id
      order by avg(salary) desc
     ) e
where rownum = 1;
```

In Oracle 12C, you don't need a subquery.  You can use `fetch first 1 row only`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your logic is that you are asking Oracle to do two levels of aggregation in a single `GROUP BY`, and that isn't possible.  As a workaround, we can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT department_id, AVG(salary) AS avg_salary,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(salary) DESC) rn
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY department_id
)

SELECT department_id, avg_salary
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If two departments might be tied for the highest average salary, then you may replace `ROW_NUMBER` above with either `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply rewrite your query as follows. There are many ways to achieve this.

```
Select department_id, max(avg_Salary) from (
 select department_id, avg(salary) as avg_Salary
From employees
Group by department_id)
Group by department_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select BOTH average salary per department AND maximum average salary aming departments then you should try the following code:

```
with qr as (
    select department_id, avg(salary) as dept_avg_salary
      from employees 
     group by department_id
)
select qr.department_id
     , qr.dept_avg_salary
     , (select max(dept_avg_salary) from qr) as max_avg_salary
  from qr
```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

To get average salary for each department and also the maximum average salary from **all** departments use this query:

```
with sal as (
Select department_id,  avg(salary) avg_salary
From employees
Group by department_id)
select 
  DEPARTMENT_ID, AVG_SALARY,
  max(AVG_SALARY) over () MAX_AVG_SALARY
from sal
```

The first subquery is a simple aggregation of the `AVG_SALARY`.
In the second step you use *analytic function* to get the global maximum of the averages. You get the global maximum by ommiting the `PARTITION BY` clause
using only `OVER()`

Answer (score 0):

The next query displays **the average salary for each department** and also **the maximum average salary from the departments**:

```
SELECT
  department_id,
  CAST(AVG(salary) AS NUMBER(8, 4)) AS dept_avg_salary,
  CAST(MAX(AVG(salary)) OVER () AS NUMBER(8, 4)) AS max_avg_salary
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
```

**Sample output:**

```
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| DEPARTMENT_ID | DEPT_AVG_SALARY | MAX_AVG_SALARY |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|             1 | 1241.7465       | 1241.7465      |
|             2 | 1191.2267       | 1241.7465      |
|             5 | 1189.8193       | 1241.7465      |
|             4 | 1201.4198       | 1241.7465      |
|             3 | 1212.7079       | 1241.7465      |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Test it here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a3c4057eab034ee1707f92f69125a338.